# How to ban CocoaPods add `-ObjC` to the OtherLinkerFlag

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

When I use CocoaPods , I see CocoaPods automatically add `-ObjC` to the `Other linker flags` in Xcode . So , can I do something to prevent CocoaPods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mainTarget = 'yourTarget'
def func1
  i=0
  while i<=10
    puts "func1 at: #{Time.now}"
    sleep(1)
    i=i+1
    debugSetting = "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-#{$mainTarget}/Pods-#{$mainTarget}.debug.xcconfig" 
    releaseSetting = "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-#{$mainTarget}/Pods-#{$mainTarget}.release.xcconfig" 
    if File::exist?(debugSetting) && File::exist?(releaseSetting)
      puts "当前文件已存在,删除可恶的-ObjC"
        fileStr = File.open(debugSetting).read
        puts "当前内容为 :\n #{fileStr}"
        fileStr["-ObjC"] = ""
        puts "删除 -ObjC后 :\n #{fileStr}"
        file = File.open(debugSetting,"w+")
    file.puts fileStr
    file.close

    puts "当前文件已存在,删除可恶的-ObjC"
        fileStr = File.open(releaseSetting).read
        puts "当前内容为 :\n #{fileStr}"
        fileStr["-ObjC"] = ""
        puts "删除 -ObjC后 :\n #{fileStr}"
        file = File.open(releaseSetting,"w+")
    file.puts fileStr
    file.close
        i = 11;
    end
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  t1 = Thread.new{ func1()}
  t1.join
end
```

To delete the `-ObjC` flag , I can use the `post_install` hook in the `Podfile` file a. Like above.

But after I deleted the `-ObjC` flag , I found do that is helpless. The `CocoaPods` uses `workspace` in Xcode to manager the static library which pods sources are contained in . Without the `-ObjC` flag , Xcode can't compile and link  the part of sources which are not specific called. The `-ObjC` flag is necessary using CocoaPods.

I am a poor man . My english is poor ,too.